# Setting an attribute's name to match a substring of another element's attribute

Tags: xslt, ibm-datapower, jsonx

I'm writing an XSLT that, among other things, locates certain elements that have a "name" attribute with a value that starts with a dash ('-').
When such attribute is found, the xslt creates an xsl:attribute, which name is all the text that comes after the "name" attribute's dash.

So, for instance, suppose I have the following XML segment:

```
<someelement>
    <json:string name="-style">display: block; white-space: pre; border: 2px     
                       solid #c77; padding: 0 1em 0 1em; margin: 1em; 
                        background-color: #fdd; color: black</json:string>
                     [... some extra elements here ...]
</someelement>
```

And I want it to become

```
<someelement style="display: block; white-space: pre; border: 2px solid #c77; 
                   padding: 0 1em 0 1em; margin: 1em; background-color: #fdd; 
                   color: black">
                 [... some extra elements here ...]
</someelement>
```

Currenty, I'm trying several variations on the following XSLT:

```
  <!-- Match string|number|boolean|null elements with a "name" attribute -->
  <xsl:template match="json:string[@name] | json:number[@name] | json:boolean[@name] | json:null[@name]">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="starts-with(@name,'-')">
        <xsl:attribute name="{substring(./[@name],2,string-length(./@name) - 1)}">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:element name="{@name}">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
```

And to be specific, this is the line that puzzles me:

```
<xsl:attribute name="{substring(./[@name],2,string-length(./@name) - 1)}">
```

To be even more specific, the part in it which doesn't work is the string-length part. If I replace the entire string-length part with a number, say 2, it works just fine.

And yes, I know that substring-after would suite me better. 
I did try the following, but it doesn't work either:

```
<xsl:attribute name="{substring-after(./[@name],'-')}">
```

I'm sure this is some kind of syntactic error.

P.S. - I'm using XMLSPY for my tests.

Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: You are misusing square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[starts-with(@name, '-')]">
    <xsl:attribute name="{substring(@name, 2)}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>    
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Test: http://xsltransform.net/6r5Gh3g

Note that this will fail if these "special" elements are not first to be processed: http://xsltransform.net/6r5Gh3g/1 If this is a possibility, you must also match the parent element and control the order of processing from there:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[starts-with(@name, '-')]">
    <xsl:attribute name="{substring(@name, 2)}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>    
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[*[starts-with(@name, '-')]]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[starts-with(@name, '-')]"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()[not(starts-with(@name, '-'))]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

http://xsltransform.net/6r5Gh3g/3

Comment: Thanks, but I do want to have the string-length perform well inside the substring. How can I make that work? : <xsl:attribute name="{substring(./[@name],2,string-length(./@name) - 1)}">

Comment: @dotaneli It is not necessary to use `string-length()` here. See the definition of the substring() function: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-substring

Comment: Thanks, you are ofcourse correct. But if I trey that: <xsl:attribute name="{substring(./@name,2)}">, I get this from XMLSPY: XSLT 2.0 Debugging Error: Illegal attribute name. Current XML node is     <json:string name="-xmlns">'http://www.google.com'</json:string>.

Comment: @dotaneli That's another issue. `xmlns` is not a valid attribute name, because the string is reserved for declaring a namespace. In fact, no name in XML should start with "xml": http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-common-syn

Comment: P.S. It looks like you are trying to reconstruct some original XML document from a badly transformed mutation. If so, it would be better to address the problem at its source.

Comment: Thank you, @michael.hor257k. Indeed it seems that since my XML had "-xmlns" attributes in couldn't be parsed. Regarding your note about the bad transformation, you are indeed correct. I can't, however, control that structure. It is given to me as is.

Comment: @dotaneli You may have bigger issues than you think. `xmlns` is a *namespace declaration*, not an *attribute*. It needs to be handled differently. Moreover, a default namespace is inherited by the descendant elements - so you need to be careful how you construct those too, without breaking the inheritance.

Comment: Right again, thanks. Handling elements with the name "-xml" is not that hard since I can use xsl:choose to filter those out and create a namespace instead of an attribute.

Comment: As I said, I suspect it may not be as easy as that - but I don't see the entire picture. In any case, I believe your current question has been answered?

Comment: @dotaneli Was it not?

Comment: This was indeed the issue. Thank you so much, @michael.hor257k

Comment: turns out the problem was the "xmlns" "attirubte", rather than the original xsl code. But your solution above did not focus on that. I want to accept the relevant answer, but it's in your comment.